# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 15.5]'

Tags: ios, iphone, slider, mpmovieplayercontroller

i find this problem but did't give me answer,

while i set value to custum slider then given me error as below

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 15.5]'**

below is my code while i set cusumslider value using MPMoviePlayerController

```
double loadTime = floor(moviePlayerController.playableDuration);
    double currentTime = floor(moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime);
    double totalTime = floor(moviePlayerController.duration);
    [self setTimeLabelValues:currentTime totalTime:totalTime];

    NSLog(@"%f",currentTime);
    custom_slider.value = ceil(currentTime);
```

also try  with `custom_slider.value = ceilf(currentTime);` but did't sloved this issues

while i comment on `custom_slider.value = ceil(currentTime);` this line then application work fine.

please help me out

Comment: Sounds as if you are receiving invalid values from `moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime`. When is that code being run? Are you awaiting the movie playback to have started before attempting to fetch that value?

Comment: thanks for help found the answer...

Comment: Why dont you go ahead and answer your question with the correct answer then, so that future visitors have your answer helping them?

Comment: replace custom_slider.value = ceil(currentTime); with custom_slider.value =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",currentTime] floatValue]; and slove my answer